# How does Google's Postini spam filter route mail to your destination mail server?

Tags: email, spam-prevention, postini

I get my email through a generic hosted mail provider and I want to set up Postini for spam filtering.  Postini has you change your MX records to the Postini servers.

What is the process for Postini to route the mail back to the destination email server for my domain?

Comment: Flagged this as 'off topic' as Postini shutdown over a year ago - http://postini-transition.googleapps.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postini acts as a filtering SMTP relay.  You set your MX records to Postini's servers, and tell Postini what the original MX records were.

Servers delivering mail to your domain check the MX records, and deliver the message to Postini.  Postini rejects the spam and then itself sends the non-spam to the original servers using the same SMTP process as when it received the message (except for the EHLO).

Ideally, you configure the original servers to only accept mail from Postini, so that spammers can't bypass Postini by sending directly to those servers (e.g. if the mail server and A record are the same, the spammer is likely to try the A record as well).

Comment: Where is this configuration done in the Postini administration console?  I'm not seeing it.

Comment: I found the answer - You go to the Email Config level, choose the Inbound Servers and click Delivery Manager. Clicking Edit lets you enter your server ip address and/or DNS info.settings.